# .Net Framework 4.7 Advanced Series not available as windows feature

Tags: .net, windows, .net-4.7

On my windows 10 PC I have a windows feature (control panel > programs > programs and feautres > turn windows features on or off) called .Net Framework 4.7 advanced series.  I am trying to enable a feature under that folder on another users PC, but their PC is a windows 7 PC.  I have searched around, but I have not determined what causes this set of features to show up.  We both have .net 4.7+ installed on our machines.  Is this installed as a feature in visual studio?  Does anyone have any insight into what causes this set of features to appear?

Update: these are the features I am trying to activate.[image: features]

Comment: It is pre-installed on Win10, but not on Win7.  So it isn't point-and-click on Win7.  "trying to enable a feature" is quite unnecessarily vague.

Comment: Do you know what I need to install to get it to appear in windows 7?

Comment: If you don't tell me what feature you need then I can't guess what button you need to push.

Comment: Added a screenshot of what I am trying to enable/install.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I've run into the same trouble.

Comment: It's been a long time but I think it was related to installing some additional visual studio features.  Open up the visual studio installer app and try installing features that relate to what your trying to do.  I don't remember which specific feature it was at this point.